# Is it possible to insert a pdf file in wxFormBuilder?

Tags: user-interface, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I am wondering if it is possible to insert a pdf document in a wxFormBuilder project or I have to do that manually by changing code in wxwidgets project. As I saw, it is possible to do that for image formats (bmp,png,jpg, ... , for example by inserting a file_path of a image in wxScrolledWindow), but I was not able to find similar option for pdf documents both on web and in wxFormBuilder itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the problem with doing it manually? PDF is not an image format - its more of a document...

Comment: I asked just to be sure that I did not miss this option in wxFormBuilder  before I start doing it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no built-in PDF renderer in wxWidgets.